# Cannot get cookie in middleware with node and angular

Tags: node.js, angular, cookies, authentication

I am using nodejs, express, cookie-parser and angular 6. Right now angular runs in `http://localhost:4200` and node/express in `http://localhost:3000`. I also put

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

in my `app.js` in node, so both angular and node can communicate.

In my login route I create an http-only cookie with the token and then I send back a JSON with some info and the user id

```
res.cookie("SESSIONID", token, {httpOnly:true, secure:true});
res.json({ success:true, msg:'you are logged in', userid: resolved.id});
```

I suppose that the SESSIONID cookie is send with every request back to the server , so I dont have to set it myself before every request

In my middleware, I want to get the token from the cookie in order to check it. So, I do

```
const token = req.cookies.SESSIONID;
console.log('token from validate : ', token);
//check token and expiration, either next(); or redirect back
```

in my routes I have

```
router.get('cms/account', myMiddleware.required(), (req, res)=>{
  res.json({ msg:'profile data'});  
});
```

My profile service contacts the account route of node

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProfileService {

  constructor(private http:Http) { }
  getProfile(){    
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/cms/account').pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }
}
```

my profile service should render some profile data

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProfileService } from '../../services/profile.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(    private profileService: ProfileService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.profileService.getProfile().subscribe((data) =>{
      console.log('profileService -- ', data);
    })

  }
}
```

After I login I go to `http://localhost:4200/cms/profile`. In the console I see `token from validate :  undefined`

So I am sure that angular successfully reaches until the validation middleware, but cannot get the cookie.

I fail to understand why the cookie is not there. Is it my synatx? Is it not set at the start? Should I include it with every request ? Is it the different ports in `localhost` ? I gave as much details I could, if you need extra, just tell me. Please help me debug this, because I am lost.

Thanks

Comment: Check the storage tab in your browser developer tools and make sure that the cookie is actually set with the correct token value.

Comment: @Vivek I see a `connect.sid` cookie, that I assume is not the same as mine. Oh wait. I must forgot to include some cookie package in node. Can cookie-parser create cookies or should I create an http-only cookie with something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) and then parse it with  cookie-parser ? Thanks

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.cookie

Comment: Make sure the lines of code that creates the cookie is being executed. 
```res.cookie("SESSIONID", token, {httpOnly:true, secure:true});
res.json({ success:true, msg:'you are logged in', userid: resolved.id});```
Log the value of ```token``` before these lines and check.

Comment: Yeap, token looks normal right before I execute `res.cookie("SESSIONID", token, {httpOnly:true, secure:true});`. Also, I get the `userid`, I put it to localStorage and then I see the it my localStorage in my browser developer tools. Hey, the cookie should not appear in the browser developer tools, since it is http-only, right?

Comment: Both `console.log('req.cookies : ', req.cookies); ` and `console.log('req.signedCookies : ', req.signedCookies);` give back `{}`. So, nothing is set, or I dont have the right syntax to get the cookies?

Comment: The syntax to get the cookies seems correct. Try removing httpOnly when setting the cookie and see the browser dev tools if they are being set.

Comment: I did  `res.cookie("SESSIONID", token, {httpOnly:false, secure:false});` and still `connect.sid` is the only cookie, not any SESSIONID. Maybe its because angular runs in its own server in `http://localhost:4200` and node/express in `http://localhost:3000`. But I think that counts as same root domain. Also I created the angular folder in the same folder where I keep my node/express server...

Comment: @Vivek Good news. if I do `res.cookie("SESSIONID", token, {httpOnly:true, secure:false});` it works because I dont have https right now. BUT the problem is that I can only get the cookie via node. Via angular I still have the same problem. So, this is a problem of different domains now? Thanks again

Comment: @slevin, were you able to resolve this issue for yourself?  If yes, can you please advise how you did it?